# Error building JZMQ on Fedora-18 (specifically the "make" phase)

Tags: make, fedora

I'm trying to build JZMQ on Fedora-18/64bit, but am experiencing a build error during the "make" phaze. Here (next) is my environment, followed by the error (at the end). Can anyone provide advice on how to fix this? Thanks in advance. (See info below).

```
user@e6510$ echo ${JAVA_HOME}
/usr/java/latest

user@e6510$ ${JAVA_HOME}/bin/java -version
java version "1.7.0_17"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_17-b02)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.7-b01, mixed mode)
user@e6510$ 

user@e6510$ rpm -qa | grep zeromq
zeromq-devel-2.2.0-4.fc18.x86_64
zeromq-2.2.0-4.fc18.x86_64
zeromq3-3.2.2-2.fc18.x86_64
user@e6510$ 

user@e6510$ python -V
Python 2.7.3
user@e6510$ 

user@e6510$ git clone https://github.com/nathanmarz/jzmq.git
Cloning into 'jzmq'...
remote: Counting objects: 611, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (206/206), done.
remote: Total 611 (delta 317), reused 555 (delta 290)
Receiving objects: 100% (611/611), 305.14 KiB, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (317/317), done.
user@e6510$
```

.

```
user@e6510$ cd jzmq
user@e6510$ ./autogen.sh
autoreconf: Entering directory `.'
autoreconf: configure.in: not using Gettext
autoreconf: running: aclocal -I config --force -I config
autoreconf: configure.in: tracing
autoreconf: running: libtoolize --copy --force
libtoolize: putting auxiliary files in AC_CONFIG_AUX_DIR, `config'.
libtoolize: copying file `config/ltmain.sh'
libtoolize: putting macros in AC_CONFIG_MACRO_DIR, `config'.
libtoolize: copying file `config/libtool.m4'
libtoolize: copying file `config/ltoptions.m4'
libtoolize: copying file `config/ltsugar.m4'
libtoolize: copying file `config/ltversion.m4'
libtoolize: copying file `config/lt~obsolete.m4'
autoreconf: running: /usr/bin/autoconf --include=config --force
autoreconf: running: /usr/bin/autoheader --include=config --force
autoreconf: running: automake --add-missing --copy --force-missing
configure.in:31: installing 'config/compile'
configure.in:28: installing 'config/config.guess'
configure.in:28: installing 'config/config.sub'
configure.in:14: installing 'config/install-sh'
configure.in:14: installing 'config/missing'
Makefile.am: installing './INSTALL'
src/Makefile.am: installing 'config/depcomp'
autoreconf: Leaving directory `.'
user@e6510$
```

.

```
user@e6510$ ./configure
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... /usr/bin/mkdir -p
checking for gawk... gawk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking how to create a ustar tar archive... gnutar
checking build system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking host system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking how to print strings... printf
checking for style of include used by make... GNU
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking dependency style of gcc... gcc3
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /usr/bin/sed
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /usr/bin/grep
checking for egrep... /usr/bin/grep -E
checking for fgrep... /usr/bin/grep -F
checking for ld used by gcc... /usr/bin/ld
checking if the linker (/usr/bin/ld) is GNU ld... yes
checking for BSD- or MS-compatible name lister (nm)... /usr/bin/nm -B
checking the name lister (/usr/bin/nm -B) interface... BSD nm
checking whether ln -s works... yes
checking the maximum length of command line arguments... 1572864
checking whether the shell understands some XSI constructs... yes
checking whether the shell understands "+="... yes
checking how to convert x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu file names to x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu format... func_convert_file_noop
checking how to convert x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu file names to toolchain format... func_convert_file_noop
checking for /usr/bin/ld option to reload object files... -r
checking for objdump... objdump
checking how to recognize dependent libraries... pass_all
checking for dlltool... no
checking how to associate runtime and link libraries... printf %s\n
checking for ar... ar
checking for archiver @FILE support... @
checking for strip... strip
checking for ranlib... ranlib
checking command to parse /usr/bin/nm -B output from gcc object... ok
checking for sysroot... no
checking for mt... no
checking if : is a manifest tool... no
checking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -E
checking for ANSI C header files... yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for sys/stat.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... yes
checking for string.h... yes
checking for memory.h... yes
checking for strings.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking for objdir... .libs
checking for gcc option to produce PIC... -fPIC -DPIC
checking if gcc PIC flag -fPIC -DPIC works... yes
checking if gcc static flag -static works... no
checking if gcc supports -c -o file.o... yes
checking if gcc supports -c -o file.o... (cached) yes
checking whether the gcc linker (/usr/bin/ld -m elf_x86_64) supports shared libraries... yes
checking whether -lc should be explicitly linked in... no
checking dynamic linker characteristics... GNU/Linux ld.so
checking how to hardcode library paths into programs... immediate
checking whether stripping libraries is possible... yes
checking if libtool supports shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build static libraries... yes
checking for gawk... (cached) gawk
checking whether gcc and cc understand -c and -o together... yes
checking for g++... g++
checking whether we are using the GNU C++ compiler... yes
checking whether g++ accepts -g... yes
checking dependency style of g++... gcc3
checking how to run the C++ preprocessor... g++ -E
checking for ld used by g++... /usr/bin/ld -m elf_x86_64
checking if the linker (/usr/bin/ld -m elf_x86_64) is GNU ld... yes
checking whether the g++ linker (/usr/bin/ld -m elf_x86_64) supports shared libraries... yes
checking for g++ option to produce PIC... -fPIC -DPIC
checking if g++ PIC flag -fPIC -DPIC works... yes
checking if g++ static flag -static works... no
checking if g++ supports -c -o file.o... yes
checking if g++ supports -c -o file.o... (cached) yes
checking whether the g++ linker (/usr/bin/ld -m elf_x86_64) supports shared libraries... yes
checking dynamic linker characteristics... (cached) GNU/Linux ld.so
checking how to hardcode library paths into programs... immediate
checking for pkg-config... /usr/bin/pkg-config
checking pkg-config is at least version 0.9.0... yes
checking for ZeroMQ... yes
checking zmq.h usability... yes
checking zmq.h presence... yes
checking for zmq.h... yes
checking for zmq_init in -lzmq... yes
checking for javac... /usr/java/latest/bin/javac
checking for javah... /usr/java/latest/bin/javah
checking for jar... /usr/java/latest/bin/jar
checking for jni.h in /usr/java/latest/include... yes
checking that generated files are newer than configure... done
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating Makefile
config.status: creating src/Makefile
config.status: creating perf/Makefile
config.status: creating src/config.hpp
config.status: executing depfiles commands
config.status: executing libtool commands
user@e6510$
```

HERE IS WHERE THE PROBLEM IS...
.

```
user@e6510$ make
Making all in src
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/user/jzmq/src'
make[1]: *** No rule to make target `classdist_noinst.stamp', needed by `org/zeromq/ZMQ.class'.  Stop.
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/user/jzmq/src'
make: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
user@e6510$
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

I worked on this and figured it out myself. Here is the complete solution including the additional steps I added to overcome the problem indicated above:

```
user$ git clone https://github.com/nathanmarz/jzmq.git
user$ cd jzmq
user$ ./autogen.sh
user$ ./configure
user$ touch src/classdist_noinst.stamp
user$ cd src
user$ CLASSPATH=.:./.:$CLASSPATH javac -d . org/zeromq/ZMQ.java org/zeromq/ZMQException.java org/zeromq/ZMQQueue.java org/zeromq/ZMQForwarder.java org/zeromq/ZMQStreamer.java

user$ cd ..
user$ make
user$ sudo make install
```

I hope this helps others.

NMV

Comment: Exactly the fix I needed on Ubuntu.

Comment: Glad this helped. :)